# Unable to retrieve archiveId using definition job in AWS Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-glacier

I am currently working on deleting an archive from AWS Glacier using the AWS CLI. I have initiated a job using the **`aws glacier initiate-job`** command, after job completed I try to retrieve the **`archiveId`** by using **`aws glacier get-job-output`**, but I am unable to find the **`archiveId`** in the output.

Here is the command I am using:

```bash
aws glacier get-job-output --account-id 123456678 --job-id aws-job-id --vault-name my-vault output.json
```

Output of the above command:

```json
{
    "status": 200,
    "acceptRanges": "bytes",
    "contentType": "application/json"
}
```

The output I receive does not contain the archiveId, which is essential for the subsequent deletion process. I have also checked the following aws [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/deleting-vaults-cli.html#Deleting-A-Nonempty-Vaults-CLI-Implementation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the command you ran:

```
aws glacier get-job-output --account-id 123456678 --job-id aws-job-id --vault-name my-vault output.json
```

Note the last parameter: `output.json`

This specified that you would like the output stored (on your local disk) in a file called `output.json`.

Take a look at that file and you should find some output like:

```json
{
    "VaultARN": "arn:aws:glacier:us-west-2:0123456789012:vaults/my-vault",
    "InventoryDate": "2015-04-07T00:26:18Z",
    "ArchiveList": [
        {
            "ArchiveId": "kKB7ymWJVpPSwhGP6ycSOAekp9ZYe_--zM_mw6k76ZFGEIWQX-ybtRDvc2VkPSDtfKmQrj0IRQLSGsNuDp-AJVlu2ccmDSyDUmZwKbwbpAdGATGDiB3hHO0bjbGehXTcApVud_wyDw",
            "ArchiveDescription": "multipart upload test",
            "CreationDate": "2015-04-06T22:24:34Z",
            "Size": 3145728,
            "SHA256TreeHash": "9628195fcdbcbbe76cdde932d4646fa7de5f219fb39823836d81f0cc0e18aa67"
        }
    ]
}
```

The `ArchiveId` is in that output.